# Kendo Grid - Cell immediately and unexpectedly loses focus after trying to click(focus) inside it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid where I'm setting up my own custom columns. One of my columns will be for a kendo dropdownlist specifying the code inside the editor template. However, only in IE, if I click inside the grid cell, it focuses and shows the dropdownlist and then immediately loses focus and my dropdownlist goes away. I can't figure out whats causing this cell to lose focus magically on its own. So I was wondering if anyone knew of a hack to help prevent this from occurring. Or maybe just a point in a new direction at least. Appreciate any advice.

Kendo Columns Setup (Column Editor Template):

```
field: 'myField',
title: 'myField',
editor: function (container, options) {
       var select = $('<input id="myId"/>');
       select.attr("name", 'myAttributeName');
       // append it to the container
       select.appendTo(container);

       // initialize a Kendo UI DropwDownList
       var ddl = select.kendoDropDownList({
                     dataSource: getDataSourceTypes(options.model),
                     dataTextField: "name",
                     dataValueField: "nameId",
                     valuePrimitive: true
              });

       ddl.data("kendoDropDownList").span.width('100');
       ddl.data("kendoDropDownList").list.width('250');
       ddl.data("kendoDropDownList").open();
}
```

Comment: can you fork a plunker or kendo dojo editor so we can quickly see whats going on?

Comment: Yeah one min. Let me see what I can do

Comment: Idk if I can do that. Have a lot of code which is mostly javascript. Would take a while to get it up on plunkr only to probably make a liar out of me. It's an enterprise app as well so I have to be careful of what code I can post.

Comment: Sure thats fine. I was I guess hoping for a slimmed down example with dummy data that reproduces this issue so we can run in IE. From your description I can't see it being terribly difficult to fork some isolated example

Comment: scniro, have you found a solution to this problem? I have this problem in my project, too